# Azure AD B2C Redirects with a "#" before the id_token

Tags: python, django, azure-ad-b2c

I've created a B2C setup, based on some documentation. I've referred to the following link.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ad/2015/09/16/azure-ad-b2c-and-b2b-are-now-in-public-preview/

So I have setup a redirect_uri, say,

**"http s://mycompany.com/login/"**

and used Google as my identity provider. However, when I do a sign-up / sign-in, the system redirects me from the sign-up / sign-in page to

**"http s://mycompany.com/login/#id_token=eyJ0eXAi..."**

The redirect URL returned by B2C contains an "id_token" variable, and upon checking it in "http://calebb.net/", the details it contains are as expected.

The issue I have is with the hash "#" mark after the redirect_uri, and before the id_token variable.   Because of the hash, the id_token variable is not sent to our server, because of the default behavior of browsers to not send anything after the hash mark. The hash mark is a fragment identifier.

Thus I am unable to obtain the value of the id_token.

Is there a way to overcome this limitation, so that our server application can obtain the value of id_token from the URL returned by the B2C system? Or is this like a bug in B2C that needs fixing?

I am using a Python/Django web application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Pass "response_mode" parameter value as "query" or "form_post" in policy linking URL to overcome the # issue.

For more information, please review: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-oauth-code

Answer (score 2):

I'm not allowed to comment also,

If you are using AngularJS for front-end then enable `HTML5` mode.

I've used this `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

According to [AngularJS: Developer Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

> In HTML5 mode, the $location service getters and setters interact with
>   the browser URL address through the HTML5 history API. This allows for
>   use of regular URL path and search segments, instead of their hashbang
>   equivalents. If the HTML5 History API is not supported by a browser,
>   the $location service will fall back to using the hashbang URLs
>   automatically. This frees you from having to worry about whether the
>   browser displaying your app supports the history API or not; the
>   $location service transparently uses the best available option.
>
> Opening a regular URL in a legacy browser -> redirects to a hashbang
>   URL Opening hashbang URL in a modern browser -> rewrites to a regular
>   URL Note that in this mode, Angular intercepts all links (subject to
>   the "Html link rewriting" rules below) and updates the url in a way
>   that never performs a full page reload.

Comment: Could you explain why enabling HTML5 mode would help address the OP's issue?  That might make for an even better answer/solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not (yet) allowed to comment, so I have to put my remark in an answer.
I had the same problem with the NodeJS B2C sample some minutes ago. I put a POST route on what is your *http s://mycompany.com/login/* endpoint

```
app.post('/',
passport.authenticate('azuread-openidconnect', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
    function(req, res) {
      log.info('We received a POST from AzureAD.');
      log.info(req.body.id_token);
      res.redirect('/');
     });
```

and then channeled it into the passport JavaScript libraries authenticate.

May be this gives you an indication and you can transfer it to Python/Django.